# Linking 2 databases in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am new to SQL Server database.

I have 2 databases DB1(Table T1 is therein this DB) and DB2(Table T2 is therein this DB) in same sql server. I want to join T1 and T2 in sql server. I came across the concept called DBlink. can we create DB link in this scenario(If Yes, Please let me how to create it.)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Before asking here, you should ask search engines. What did you find out by looking at the documentation for this feature? What exactly aren't you understanding/can't implement/are stuck on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

dblink is a feature of Oracle, not Sql Server.
Corresponding feature ins mssql is called linked servers, and enables you to add links to different server, not database. In your case, you don't need this. To join tables from different databases on the same server, just include database name in your query:

```
select top 100 t1.* from [databse_name].[schema_name].[table_name] as t1
```

Comment: And also make sure the connected user has rights to both places.